# Difference between surface tension and interfacial tension

Tags: fluid-statics

Is there really a difference between surface tension and interfacial tension?

Comment: This is something you could have easily looked up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Interfacial tension* is the tension force at the interface where two mediums meet.
- *Surface tension* is the tension at the boundary of a medium.

In the case of water-and-air or any fluid-within-another-fluid that do not immediately mix, then the concepts are synonymous. But you can also imagine a blob of liquid floating about in empty space, in which case the interfacial tension is not defined (because there is no other medium than the liquid).